# Why is 'parts' not working in XML Fragment property binding?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an XML fragment which works fine when using

```
value="{path: 'ReceivedQuantity', formatter: '.formatQuantity'}"
```

But if I want to send multiple parameters to this formatter function, using parts, it no longer works. The function isn't called. I have tried putting it into a separate formatter.js file, this has the same result.

```
value="{parts: [{path: 'ReceivedQuantity'}, {path: 'Currency'}], formatter: '.formatQuantity'}"
```

I am using sap.ui.core.Fragment.load to load the fragment in the controller.

```
sap.ui.core.Fragment.load({name: "myapp.view.ColumnTemplate", 
controller: this}).then(function(oFragment){
//that.getView().addDependent(oFragment);
oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: "/PoItemSet",
    template: oFragment,
    templateShareable: true,
    filters: aFilters
    });
 });
```

Is there an known issue, or a workaround, if you want to achieve this?

I am using SAPUI5 v1.71.57
The fragment is a ColumnListItem used as a template for a sap.m.Table for the row bindings.

Comment: Did you have the configuration flag  `data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"` in the bootstrap script ?

[Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.57/#/topic/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0)

Comment: @depth1 yes, this was already present, from the template wizard when I first created the app in the sapwebide.

Comment: What happen if you do your composite binding without specifying the formatter option ? : `{parts: [{path: 'ReceivedQuantity'}, {path: 'Currency'}]}`